# Не работает фильтр чёрного цвета в rgb для opencv поиска обьектов

Tags: python, opencv

Извините за нубские вопросы. Продолжаю работу над кодом распознавания черного цвета, только вот когда хочу найти цвет на видео получаю уйму лишних обьектов. Хотя фильтры-маски те же самые.

```
while(True):

    _, frame = cap.read()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    black1 = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)

    black2 = np.array([179,50,70], np.uint8)

  #  black2 = np.array([179,255,70], np.uint8)

    black_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, black1, black2)

    kernel = np.ones((7, 7), "uint8")

    black_mask = cv2.dilate(black_mask, kernel)

    res_black = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = black_mask)

    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(black_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for c in cnts:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if len(approx) > 3 and area > 200:

            image = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Black detected", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 255))

    cv2.imshow("Video from camera", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: В `cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 0), (40, 40, 40))` тройки ведь не RGB, так?

Comment: я если честно не знаю как перевести в rgb, не могу найти в интернете примера, хочу найти черный цвет с картинки

Comment: Если надо выделить именно черный - используйте cv.threshold. Не надо мудрить с HSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось более-менее выделить светофоры вот таким кодом:

```
import cv2 

image = cv2.imread('traffic_light.jpg')

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (7,7), 0)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0,0,0), (179,50,55))

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if len(approx) > 3 and area > 200:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0,255,0), -1)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
```

Только не просите объяснить, я с OpenCV особо не знаком, делал методом научного тыка.

[image: -]

Comment: Ваша помощь просто неоценима, есть ли возможность разпознавать области на видео и выделять их квадратом на пример?Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Требуемая цветовая модель для функции inRange(src, lowerb, upperb, dst) в OpenCV-это HSV.

Параметры lowerb и upperb задают необходимые нижние и верхние границы цвета в формате HSV. В OpenCV для HSV диапазон оттенков составляет [0,179], диапазон насыщенности - [0,255], а диапазон значений - [0,255].
[Источник.](https://coderoad.ru/48689776/OpenCV-InRange-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80)

Попробуйте:

```
czarny = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 16))
```

переводил схему [тут](https://colorscheme.ru/color-converter.html).

Comment: 1. Для InRange не важна цветовая модель.  Да, чаще используют именно hsv, но это совершенно  не обязательно. 2.  Ахроматичные цвета не имеет оттенка, но на практике, из-за шумов, оттенки будут, поэтому лучше как-так  (0, 0, 0)-(180, 5, 16). см. пост GrAnd

Comment: Согласен. Только 180 вне диапазона. Оф. документация гласит:
Note
For HSV, Hue range is [0,179], Saturation range is [0,255] and Value range is [0,255]. Different softwares use different scales. So if you are comparing OpenCV values with them, you need to normalize these ranges.